# What books have more about the Greyhawk deities Istus and Ralishaz?

Tags: product-identification, lore, religions-and-deities, greyhawk

My group and I are beginning to start a game of dnd-5e.

While beginning to build our new characters we have noted that in the appendix B of the Player's Handbook among Greyhawk deities there are a couple of names that sound new to us like Istus and Ralishaz (and a couple more, but a player is especially interested in these two).

We can obviously play without knowing anything more than what is written in the table of the appendix but having a little more lore will be nice.

Is there an official reference where I can find more information on these deities, even just a little paragraph as the one presented in the D&D 3.5 Player's Handbook indicating common worshipers and basic relations of the deity and other members of the pantheon?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there's no new Greyhawk sources published for D&D 5e yet, there's a vast wealth of them from previous editions and online.

In 3.5e days the [Living Greyhawk Gazetteer](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0786917431) was the latest book with all the Greyhawk world info including details on every deity, but there's various previous Greyhawk boxed sets etc. (The Fantasy Game Setting was for 1e, then Greyhawk Wars for 2e, then From the Ashes in late 2e) that have it too.  You can buy [all these and other sources in PDF from dndclassics.com](http://www.dmsguild.com/browse.php?filters=0_0_0_0_45357_0_0_0).

Also [on the Canonfire! wiki](http://www.canonfire.com/cf/modules.php?name=Topics), there's plenty of info on all the deities.  In fact, the Greyhawk deities are so popular [many of them have their own Wikipedia entry, including Istus and Ralishaz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greyhawk_deities).